# Changing OWIN AuthenticationMiddleware options during runtime

Tags: asp.net, owin, openid-connect, owin-middleware

In my app an external component registers an `AuthenticationMiddleware<TOptions>` middleware during app startup, specifically an `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware` instance. I'd like to change this instance's configuration with the public `Options` property available on all authentication middlewares, later at one point after the app startup. Is this possible?

I can't change the startup process of this middleware and do the configuration there (though I can add my own middlewares). I'd like to somehow access the middleware instance after its creation, possibly by accessing the middleware object via `OwinContext`, though I haven't found a way to do this.

**Details:**

I'd like to change the options of `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware` in the following way:

```
OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware middleware = ...;
middleware.Options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = new[] { "https://sts.windows.net/some-guid/" };
```

This adds the common Microsoft Azure Active Directory tenant as a valid issues, thus allowing public SSO on the site with Microsoft IDs.

Comment: it is not recommend to change owin middleware chain at runtime. but if you want it, you can do it by register all the middleware and options into an ioc container or just add them to a global object where you can access it at runtime.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @zhimin as mentioned unfortunately I can't change how the middleware is registered (it's done by a framework).

Comment: @Troopers The OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware instance is registered by a framework with a given configuration that I need to alter. However I can't touch into the registration process to do this there, but since the Options property is public (as is the specific option I want to change) I'd like to do this afterwards.

Comment: Edit your question to show what you need to alter in the configuration of `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware` and why

Comment: I don't think I can add any more context that's actually useful, but I'll do an edit.

Comment: Added some details.